# How to edit this code to calculate CRC-32/MPEG in C#

Tags: c#, crc, crc32

I have this code which calculate CRC-32, I need to edit this code with: Polynomial 0x04C11DB7 ,Initial value: 0xFFFFFFFF , XOR:0 .
So CRC32 for string "123456789" should be"0376E6E7", I found a code, it's very slow , But it works any way.
```internal static class Crc32
{
internal static uint[] MakeCrcTable()
{
uint c;
uint[] crcTable = new uint[256];
for (uint n = 0; n < 256; n++)
{
c = n;
for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{
var res = c & 1;
c = (res == 1) ? (0xEDB88320 ^ (c >> 1)) : (c >> 1);
}
crcTable[n] = c;
}

````
            return crcTable;
        }


        internal static uint CalculateCrc32(byte[] str)
        {
            uint[] crcTable = Crc32.MakeCrcTable();
            uint crc = 0xffffffff;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                byte c = str[i];
                crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[(crc ^ c) & 0xFF];
            }

            return ~crc; //(crc ^ (-1)) >> 0;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Why don't you just try substituting the existing values?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I tried, but I didn't get the desired result

Comment: What exactly is the "desired result" for what input? Do you know if your desired CRC is reflected or not? Your desired CRC might be MPEG-2 or it might be JAMCRC.

Comment: We assume this our data "123456789", The expected CRC32 should be"0376E6E7"

Comment: I forgot , That is no reflections input or output.

Comment: Put the data and expectation in the question, not in a comment. As well as the full definition of the CRC, with reflections.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include _all_ of the information.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the added comments, what you are looking for is [CRC-32/MPEG-2](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-mpeg-2), which reverses the direction of the CRC, and eliminates the final exclusive-or, compared to the implementation you have, which is a [CRC-32/ISO-HDLC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-iso-hdlc).

To get there, you need to flip the CRC from reflected to forward. You bit-flip the polynomial to get `0x04c11db7`, check the high bit instead of the low bit, reverse the shifts, both in the table generation and use of the table, and exclusive-or with the high byte of the CRC instead of the low byte.

To remove the final exclusive-or, remove the tilde at the end.

Comment: Is this will solve the problem?

Comment: thank you very much , You put me in the right direction. And excuse me I'm just started C# one month ago, Thanks again.